# NHibernate session management/patterns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I have been googling around to find some answers about repository and unit of work patterns that can be used with NHibernate. I have found a few good examples but still have a fundamental problem. We have a business layer which is used by WCF service, Windows Services and and MVC project. Now I need to implement nhibernate as my orm tool with the usage of repository and unit of work patterns. I also need to use the right contexttype(web/call/...) for each technology. Can anybody point me to some articles or give me some pointers which can achieve this. Please note that I will need to use the same business layer with WCF calls, Windows Service and MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what the lifetime of your NHibernate session is to be. If it is only for the duration of the call into the BL layer, you could wrap your BL calls with a using(session.Open). If your nhibernate session should last longer (for the duration of your web session for instance), you'll need to handle the instantiation and disposal of a longer nhibernate session within your MCV project. Hope this helps.